# Problema com exibição da sprite de personagem 2D na Unreal Engine 4

Tags: jogos, lógica, unreal-engine

Eu estava seguindo um tutorial do site da Unreal Engine 4 e em um determinado vídeo tem uma explicação de como dar movimentação a algum personagem (WASD, pular, correr e etc).

Em outro vídeo mostra como dar movimentos vivos ao personagem usando Sprites em [Flipbooks](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Paper2D/Flipbooks) dentro da Blueprint do personagem (movimentos como correr, pular e respirar mesmo parado) e ao iniciar o executável (.exe) ele faz tudo normal.

O problema é que quando ele faz tudo isso tem algo como dois bonecos sobrepostos um ao outro. Um com a animação dele parado e a outra dele correndo/pulando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fotos do blueprint:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá. Eu não conheço Unreal, mas ainda assim a sua pergunta parece fornecer poucos dos detalhes que de fato importariam pra resolver o problema. Você cita os tutoriais, mas esperar que alguém disposto a te ajudar tenha que assistí-los é um pouco demais. Eu sugeriria que você editasse a pergunta pra melhorá-la, fazendo o seguinte: (1) coloque as imagens diretamente na pergunta, pra facilitar a leitura; (2) coloque trechos do código onde você manipula as animações (pois alguém pode identificar algum erro mais facilmente).

Comment: Leonardo, não sei se já conseguiu resolver o problema, mas este tipo de pergunta vai além de assistir o tutorial que você está seguindo. Tente deixa claro o que você entende como problema, e evidencie o que você fez para chegar nele, no caso, entendi que existem dois problemas: (1) bonecos colados e (2) animação parada. Para ambos os casos é importante você colocar detalhes de como você configurou cada um, se usou blueprint e o código c++ que usou, printscreen das paginas de detalhe do personagem também.

Comment: olá Nils eu estou em posses de alguns cursos de programação c++ pra unreal e com alguns e-books sobre uso de blueprints. Já noto os erros de animação e de blueprints colados e agora não acontece mais. Nesse primeiro curso que acompanhei não tinha programação. Mas já está tudo certo agora, isso não acontece mais. muito obrigado pelo apoio.

Comment: Unreal é melhor para 3d, jogos sofisticados, já 2d é melhor Unity.

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin considere colocar uma resposta para sua própria pergunta mostrando como você fez para resolver seu problema. Outras pessoas com certeza já tiveram e ainda vão ter o mesmo problema que você.